# Mapping MS Outlook 2011 for Mac with Gmail

Tags: outlook, gmail, gmail-imap

I wonder if anybody can help with a problem I'm having with MS Outlook 2011 for Mac and Gmail.

I am trying to map them so that I mainly/always use Outlook. I have managed to follow this tutorial online (http://tinyurl.com/23h88hk) to map the inbox folder. However, whenever I delete messages on Gmail's web interface or on my BlackBerry they go to the bin folder, and Outlook doesn't map the bin/deleted items, sent items and drafts folders.

I hope this makes sense and I appreciate any help sorting this.

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you delete messages straight from the Gmail server (ie. mail.google.com or Gmail app) and NOT sync your Outlook to receive your emails BEFORE the deletion, then it makes sense that Outlook doesn't map the emails you deleted on mail.google.com or via the Gmail app.

However, you can set Outlook to delete items from the Gmail server if you delete it through Outlook.

From what I understand, you are trying to map everything verbatim between Outlook and the Gmail servers.

Does my explanation make sense or do you need further clarification?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to tidy it up so that all the folders are named the same and sync together. Therefore if I delete an e-mail on the Gmail web client then this will move it to the deleted items/trash/bin on Outlook. The same with sent items/mail and drafts. Is this possible? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using POP3 or IMAP?  For what you want done, I recommend IMAP.

Comment: Yeah, IMAP is what I'm using.

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://superuser.com/questions/335314/mac-outlook-2011-with-gmail-imap-folders-gmail-labels-not-updating